# Android: keep data of webview for next use like coockies

Tags: android, android-webview, android-websettings

i put a webview in an activity .

the webview loads TelegramWeb's page.

when i login to the telegram account it works fine.

but when i rotate screen or reopen the app it forgets all data and needs relogin to telegram account.

so i need to save some data like coockies and other necessary files.

i used setJavaScriptEnabled=true and some other setting below:

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled") public class SubActivity extends Activity {

private WebView wv1;

protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
      wv1.saveState(outState);
   }

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sub);
    Button b1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);

     wv1=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
     WebSettings ws=wv1.getSettings();
     ws.setAllowContentAccess(true);
     ws.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
     ws.setSaveFormData(true);
      wv1.setWebViewClient(new Webview());
      wv1.getSettings().getCacheMode();
      wv1.getSettings().getAllowContentAccess();
      wv1.getSettings().getSaveFormData();
      wv1.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
      wv1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
      wv1.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
      wv1.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);   
      wv1.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true); 
      wv1.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
      wv1.setSaveEnabled(true);
      if (savedInstanceState != null) 
         wv1.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
      else
      wv1.loadUrl("https://web.telegram.org/#/im");


      b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), wv1.getUrl().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

but still it needs re-login to account.

better to know that SubActivity Class start from MainActivity after checking a password.

**------**

**note:**

i added this code after wf1.loadUrl and it works on screen rotation.

```
wv1.saveState(savedInstanceState);
```

but still not works when close app and reopen it. so i have to re-login.
i think i have to save the InstanceState some where.
how can i do?

Comment: i think i should serialize Bundle directly to save some where. or cast it to an object then serialize it, so when i need it can be deserialized then down-cast to Bundle. is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use database for saving data you can use Shared Preferences where you save key-value pairs. More in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref).

Comment: Thanks for considering... but how can i save instanse State? Should i serialize then save it ?

Comment: i tried it's not useable for saveInstanceState of webview

Answer (score 0):

Try the below, it might works for cache issue,

```
wv1.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
wv1.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
```

The below works for device rotation and configuration changes

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

After this edit AndroidManifest.xml file like below
    `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"`